# $K(xy)\leq K(x)+K(y) +c$?

Tags: information-theory, turing-machines, kolmogorov-complexity

Could anyone show that for any $c$, some strings $x$ and $y$ exist, where $K(xy)>K(x)+K(y)+c$? Here $K(x)$ is the Kolmogorov complexity. I already know that $K(xy) \leq 2K(x) + K(y) +c$ and $K(xy) \leq 2\log_2(K(x)) + K(x) + K(y) +c$. But the same ideas of proof cannot be applied to this problem...

Comment: Assuming that by $xy$ you mean the usual concatenation operation, section 4 [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/kaikoura.pdf) may be relevant.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks! The chain rule of Kolmogorov complexity is definitely relative. I will fill in the answer here as soon as possible.